# GitLab LDAP integration with JumpCloud not working

Tags: ldap, cloud, gitlab

I am trying to configure GitLab server to use JumpCloud LDAP as a service, but couldn't make it work. GitLab rake command shows that connectivity to LDAP server is successful but when I try to login, an error *Could not authenticate you from Ldapmain because "Invalid Credentials".* is shown

**ldapsearch command produces output correctly:**

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.jumpcloud.com:389 -D "uid=username,ou=Users,o=org12345,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com" -w "password"  -b "ou=Users,o=org12345,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com" "(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)" sAMAccountName

# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=Users,o=org12345,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectClass=inetOrgPerson)
# requesting: sAMAccountName 
#

# username, Users, org12345, jumpcloud.com
dn: uid=username,ou=Users,o=org12345,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com

# user1, Users, org12345, jumpcloud.com
dn: uid=user1,ou=Users,o=org12345,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 3
# numEntries: 2
```

**Gitlab rake check**

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check

Checking LDAP ...

Server: ldapmain
LDAP authentication... Success
LDAP users with access to your GitLab server (only showing the first 100 results)

Checking LDAP ... Finished
```

**Error in unicorn_stdout.log**

```
I, [2016-12-29T05:52:50.947393 #7067]  INFO -- omniauth: (ldapmain) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2016-12-29T05:52:51.834803 #7067] ERROR -- omniauth: (ldapmain) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials encountered.
```

**Error shown to user**

[image]

**GitLab LDAP configuration**

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS' # remember to close this block with 'EOS' below
 main:
  label: 'LDAP'
  host: 'ldap.jumpcloud.com'
  port: 389 #Change to 636 if using LDAPS
  method: 'plain' # Change to "tls" if using LDAPS
  uid: 'sAMAccountName' # Don't change this
  bind_dn: 'uid=username,ou=Users,o=org12345,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com'
  password: 'password'
  active_directory: true
  allow_username_or_email_login: false
  block_auto_created_users: false
  base: 'ou=Users,o=org12345,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com'
  user_filter: '(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)'
EOS
```

I am certain that provided username and password are correct. Can someone please check and let me know if I am making a mistake in the configuration or is there something else I could check to solve this problem?

Thank you very much for your help

**Reponse I received from JumpCloud support on 29/Dec:**

After reviewing your configuration in addition to gitlab’s it looks like it is necessitating that the uid field = sAMAccountName. This is a samba attribute, that we currently do not support. While in JumpCloud, the uid = uid . If you are able to change that field, it looks like it should connect but it appears that gitlab requires samba schema to authenticate via LDAP.

Comment: Show your LDAP configuration  (without the password) from gitlab.rb

Comment: Added LDAP configuration details to the question

Answer (score 2):

The **bind_dn** should be the **domain\username** used to connect to the ldap server. The bind_dn and password are used to authenticate GitLab with the LDAP service.

Here is what mine looks like:

> bind_dn: 'gintra\gitlab-registrar'

Answer (score 1):

Changing `uid: 'sAMAccountName'` to `uid: 'uid'` in your config should work:

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['prevent_ldap_sign_in'] = false

##! **remember to close this block with 'EOS' below**
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS'
 main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
 label: 'Gitlab LDAP'
 host: 'ldap.jumpcloud.com'
 port: 636
 uid: 'uid'
 bind_dn: 'uid=xxx,ou=Users,o=xxx,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com'
 password: 'xxx'
 encryption: 'simple_tls' # "start_tls" or "simple_tls" or "plain"
 #     verify_certificates: true
 smartcard_auth: false
 active_directory: true
 allow_username_or_email_login: false
 lowercase_usernames: false
 block_auto_created_users: false
 base: 'ou=Users,o=xxx,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com'
 user_filter: '(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)'
 EOS
```